# Make data and methods reusable in Vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Let say i have a script like this in vue

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "BaseCardAnnotationOption",
  data() {
    return {
      includeAnnotations1: false,
      embedIntoImage: null,
      burnIntoImage: null,
      burnReduction1: false,
      maintainColor1: false,
      annotationOption1: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    deselectDisabled() {
      return this.includeAnnotations1 === false
        ? ((this.annotationOption1 = null), (this.maintainColor1 = false))
        : ((this.annotationOption1 = 0), (this.maintainColor1 = false));
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

And i am using the data variable and methods in like 4 or 5 other places . Is there a way i could put all these in a new file and just call these from a component when required . Thanks

Comment: If you're looking for a centralized store: https://vuex.vuejs.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use mixins to define some options and reuse them across your components, create a file called `someMixins.js` with following content :

```js
export default const someMixins={
data() {
    return {
      includeAnnotations1: false,
      embedIntoImage: null,
      burnIntoImage: null,
      burnReduction1: false,
      maintainColor1: false,
      annotationOption1: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    deselectDisabled() {
      return this.includeAnnotations1 === false
        ? ((this.annotationOption1 = null), (this.maintainColor1 = false))
        : ((this.annotationOption1 = 0), (this.maintainColor1 = false));
    }
  }

}
```

then import it inside the component and use as follows :

```html
<script>
import someMixins from 'path/to/someMixins.js'
export default {
  name: "BaseCardAnnotationOption",
  mixins:[someMixins]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to Boussadjra Brahim response, if you`re using Vue 3, you can import your functions inside a "script setup" all over your code.

Inside a file like '../module.js' or something else you prefer:

```
export function deselectDisabled() {

// Here you will need to modify and adapt your function to use callbacks. 

}
```

Then you can just import it and use it like:

```
<script setup>
import { deselectDisabled } from './module.js
// Now you can use your function all over your vue file.

...

</script>
```

It is new a "syntactic sugar" vue 3 is implementing and it is REALLY helpful for big projects. You can see more about this here:
https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html